# Enable image upload in WebView app Android studio

Tags: android-studio, webview, android-webview

I'm creating a WebView app with WordPress website link my WebView has an image upload option in app it is not allowed to upload images can anybody help me or give me any references to code which needed to implement to upload images. I tried some code but they're not working it ask for permission to access media but not open gallery to select images what do i do to open gallery and upload images in my WebView

Comment: You may need to get a permission to access Gallery from the user. And then pass the permission to the webview.

Comment: @c-an i did it just open the gallery select the image and then just close the gallery nothing happens after that

Comment: Have you debugged your console?